# Creating relation within the same table not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I have categories table whose sql is this in the migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->boolean('is_parent')->default(true);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('parent')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('SET NULL');
        $table->integer('priority');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and I also created following function in the category model for relationship:

```
public function categoryName(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category'); 
}
```

But, when I try to do this `<td>{{ $categoryList->categoryName->name }}</td>`, it gives the following error

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\gokarna\resources\views\admin\pages\categories.blade.php)
>   But, it works perfectly with posts table where I am fetching post category.

And, this is what I have in the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $parent = $this->category->where('is_parent', 1)->get();
    $allCategories = $this->category->get();

    return view('admin.pages.categories', compact('parent', 'allCategories'));
}
```

What is the logic behind foreign key not working with the same table?

**Edit**
`$categoryList = $allCategories` so I am getting categories. I tried renaming the column `parent` into `category_id` it gives json data when I do `{{ $categoryList->categoryName}}` but it does not give output when I do `{{ $categoryList->categoryName->name }}`.

I also tried renaming `categoryName` to `category` it does that same what the above do, it gives [image: json data] with `{{ $categoryList->category}}` but throws an error when I do this `{{ $categoryList->categoryName->name}}`.

Comment: plz post the controller action's code

Comment: Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with `_id`. However, if the foreign key on the model is not `category_name_id` you should pass the custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following to get my expected answer:

```
{{ $categoryList->category['name']}}
```

Like I told in my comments I was getting an object when I did `{{ $categoryList->category}}` but could not get the result doing `{{ $categoryList->category->name}}`.

The thing is If any object does not contain any attribute and you try to use that attribute, 
it will give you an error. But in case of array, if you use that as a key of an array, it will display null.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your method to be like this:

```php
public function categoryName(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category','parent'); 
}
```

Without adding the foreign key `'parent'` it will use the method name to get the parent object.

It's always a good practice whenever you face such a problem to `dd` the query or the results

so you can debug it like so (write this somewhere where you can test it):
`dd(Category::first()->categoryName()->toSql());` this should give you a hint of what's going on

---

You are getting this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\gokarna\resources\views\admin\pages\categories.blade.php) But, it works perfectly with posts table where I am fetching post category.

because `...->categoryName->...` in your view is null, thus making `->categoryName->name` invalid

Plus, in your controller you're not sending the `$categoryList`, i don't see that in there:

```php
public function index()
{
    $parent = $this->category->where('is_parent', 1)->get();
    $allCategories = $this->category->get();
    // no $categoryList sent here.. ?
    return view('admin.pages.categories', compact('parent', 'allCategories'));
}
```

But since it didn't show error that the $categoryList variable is not defined then it's there somewhere but you forgot to mention where to us, there's something unclear actually in your question, however.

---

## I would suggest you modify your code to be

```php
...
$table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable(); // Because `parent` is a preserved mysql keyword
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('SET NULL');
...
```

### Category Model

```php
public function category(){
    # In this case here, Laravel will look for column of method_name + _id
    # so it will look for ...category_id without manually defining the 
    # Foreign key
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
}
```

Then you can easily get it in your view like:

```
<td>{{ $whateverCategoryObjectThisIs->category->name }}</td>
```

You can include the `optional` function to prevent it from throwing if the parent category is not set like so

```
<td>{{ optional($whateverCategoryObjectThisIs->category)->name }}</td>
```

Comment: `$categoryList = $allCategories` so I am getting categories. I tried renaming the column `parent` into `category_id` it gives json data when I only do `{{ $categoryList->categoryName}}` but it does not give output when I do `{{ $categoryList->categoryName->name }}`

Comment: in my example i modified the method name to `category` instead of `categoryName` so if you modified that too, try to use `->category->name` instead of `->categoryName->name`

Comment: or in your `categoryName` method make it do this `return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category','category_id');`

Comment: note that 'category_id' is the column in your categories database table